# Удаление элементов дома через js

Tags: javascript, html, события, dom, button

Не понимаю, в чём ошибка.При нажатии на кнопку должны удалиться все p во всех дивах

```js
let p = document.getElementsByClassName('p');
    let div = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
    let deleteBtn = document.getElementById('delete');

    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < p.length; p++) {
            div[i].removeChild(p[i]);
        }
    });
```

```html
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
<div class="d">
    LLLLOOOL
    <p class="p">Hi1</p>
</div>
<div class="d">
    LLLLOOOL
    <p class="p">Hi2</p>
</div>
<div class="d">
    LLLLOOOL
    <p class="p">Hi3</p>
</div>
<div class="d">
    LLLLOOOL
    <p class="p">Hi4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `p++` - ??
2. `let div = document.getElementsByClassName('d'); // not ...('div')`
3. `getElementsByClassName` - "живая" коллекция:

   ```
   for (let i = p.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       div[i].removeChild(p[i]);
   }
   ```

А лучше:

```
document.getElementById('delete').addEventListener('click', function () {
  let div = document.getElementsByClassName('d');
  for (let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    div[i].removeChild(div[i].querySelector(".p"));
  }
});
```

```js
document.getElementById('delete').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let div = document.getElementsByClassName('d');
  for (let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    div[i].removeChild(div[i].querySelector(".p"));
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
<div class="d">
  LLLLOOOL
  <p class="p">Hi1</p>
</div>
<div class="d">
  LLLLOOOL
  <p class="p">Hi2</p>
</div>
<div class="d">
  LLLLOOOL
  <p class="p">Hi3</p>
</div>
<div class="d">
  LLLLOOOL
  <p class="p">Hi4</p>
</div>
```